# jquery mobile loader not working on android

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an hybrid application for android and iOS. This is not my first app, but I don't consider myself an expert either. At the moment I'm targeting Android 4.4 or later. For iOS I got an iPhone 4S to test, not supporting anything below iOS 9.2. To make this app I'm currently using *Phonegap Build*, which outputs version=`cli-5.2.0` and using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 as the framework to handle the UI, navigation and so on. The Javascript is being loaded locally - from the device.

Considering some server interaction takes some time to load, I was thinking to show a loading gif while the server interaction processes. For this matter I'm using a `loader` widget from jQuery Mobile. The code for the ajax request calls has the following code:

```
$.serviceCall = function(web_method, web_root, params){

    var ajax_response;
    var request_url = 'http:/some.url.com/' + web_root + '/' + web_method;

    $.mobile.loading( "show", {
        text: "loading",
        textVisible: false,
        theme: "z",
        html: ""
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: request_url,
        data: params,
    }).done(function(data){
        ajax_response = data
        ajax_response.callback = 'done';
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        var failure_details = {
            status: jqXHR.status,
            text_status: textStatus,
            error_thrown: errorThrown
        };
        ajax_response = failure_details;
        ajax_response.callback = 'fail';
    $.mobile.loading("hide");
    });

    return ajax_response;
};
```

Which works perfectly fine when accessing from a desktop browser or from ripple emulator to simulate the actual device.Once the request starts, the loader shows, hides as soon as the request ends and makes the page transition.

However, on android doesn't work. Whenever the request starts the loader doesn't show up no matter how long the request takes. Is there any trick for mobile OS that I need to apply in order to make it work?

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 sorry I completely lost your comment! I updated the question information with what you asked, please let me know if you need any additional information, thanks!

Comment: Are you using *DESKTOP APP*? What framework are you using: Angular, Express, Ember?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 jQuery Mobile, it's on the title, I'll add it to description though

Comment: Last question: are you loading JQuery Mobile from the Internet?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 nope, I have it locally

Comment: Okay. I added that to your original post. I am taking a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

check this [guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging) on how to inspect the App.

I suggest taking out `$.mobile.loading("hide");` so you can keep the loader running to see whats happening. might be a `z-index` issue or an error in the `console`

Comment: so I did this and I found 2 interesting things: first, the loader takes a bit longer appearing in android then it does on desktop environments, second: even with no `$.mobile.loading('hide')` whenever I make a transition between pages the loader disappears, is the transition happening before it can show the loader then? and how to prevent this then?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Alpizar Chinchilla -- not sure why there is a delay, try the mobile firefox browser and see if faster -- you could add a second or so timeout to hide the the loader -- eg (setTimeout(function(){
  $.mobile.loading("hide");
}, 2000);) so at least you see it -- not sure about the other problems you have but sounds like a browser issue rather than JQM -- i never used the inbuild loader, i didnt like it much myself, instead i used spin js -- http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

Comment: the problem is the loader is gone as soon as the page transition starts, I'll dig into page transition events and see if I can show it faster. On the other hand I didn't know about spin, I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

You have made a common mistake. You need to apply the `whitelist` system. It is required as of [Cordova Tools 5.0.0](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) (April 21, 2015). For *Phonegap Build*, that means since [`cli-5.1.1`](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/) (16 Jun 2015)

Add this to your `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist"      source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" /> <!-- Required for iOS9 -->
```

**NOTE YOUR APP IS NOW INSECURE. IT IS UP TO YOU TO SECURE YOUR APP.**
Add the following to your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

This *whitelist* worksheet should help.
[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

If it is not this, then there may be a JQuery Mobile setting which I may not be familiar with.

Comment: I had certainly the whiltelist plugin working, but my configuration is right now very different to the one you've suggested. I'll check it out in some hours and I'll keep you posted, since it's 1:50 am right now in here :p

Comment: I suspect you have Javascript in your index.html. In which case, you'll need the CSP (Content-Security-Policy).